# panic: SetUint using value obtained using unexported field

Tags: arrays, go, byte

From byte buffer received server, I want to copy struct.

The format of buffer is fixed size bytes as below.

```
00000000  83 27 48 12 6c 00 00 00  01 02 00 00 01 01 00 02  |.'H.l...........|
00000010  10 01 d2 02 96 49 00 00  00 00 87 d6 12 00 00 00  |.....I..........|
00000020  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 02 01 02 3c 01 01 00  00 00 01 01 01 01 18 10  |....<...........|
00000040  2c 01 90 01 01 6c 07 03  c8 02 01 02 03 9c 0a 0b  |,....l..........|
00000050  0c 00 00 00 01 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 01 01 01  |................|
00000060  01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01  01 00 01 01 01 00 00 00  |................|
```

My struct is below.

```
type HeaderT struct {
    magicValue [8]byte
    bodyLength [4]byte
    bodyVersion [1]byte
    ...
}
```

My implementation is at below.

```
func onMessageReceived(client MQTT.Client, message MQTT.Message) {
    payload := message.Payload()
    fmt.Printf("Received message on topic: %s\nMessage: \n%s\n", message.Topic(), hex.Dump(payload))

    header := HeaderT {}
    err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(payload[:]), binary.LittleEndian, &header)  // <-- error occurred at this line
    ...
}
```

My code make panic as below.

> panic: reflect: reflect.Value.SetUint using value obtained using
>   unexported field
>
> goroutine 38 [running]: reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable(0x1a8)
>           /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:231 +0x1ee reflect.Value.SetUint(0x12540e0, 0xc0001a2000, 0x1a8, 0x83)
>           /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1551 +0x2f encoding/binary.(*decoder).value(0xc000148d88, 0x12540e0,
>   0xc0001a2000, 0x1a8)
>           /usr/local/go/src/encoding/binary/binary.go:548 +0x7c6 encoding/binary.(*decoder).value(0xc000148d88, 0x125cfc0,
>   0xc0001a2000, 0x1b1)
>           /usr/local/go/src/encoding/binary/binary.go:510 +0x104 encoding/binary.(*decoder).value(0xc000148d88, 0x129fa00,
>   0xc0001a2000, 0x199)
>           /usr/local/go/src/encoding/binary/binary.go:523 +0x2c5 encoding/binary.Read(0x12fcf80, 0xc00018a150, 0x1300c60, 0x14d76d0,
>   0x1248040, 0xc0001a2000, 0x0, 0x0)
>           /usr/local/go/src/encoding/binary/binary.go:248 +0x342 main.onMessageReceived(0x13012a0, 0xc000140000, 0x1300c00,
>   0xc000192000)

Comment: `panic: reflect: reflect.Value.SetUint using value obtained using unexported field`: try to make your fields public (like magicValue [8]byte -> MagicValue [8]byte)

Comment: Capitalize the first letter of your fields.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is that none of `HeaderT`'s fields are "public".

Notice that all the fields start with a lowercase letter - that means the fields are unreachable to any code outside of your package.

From the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers):

> **Exported identifiers**
>
> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> - the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> - the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

Try Exporting them by capitalizing their names:

```
type HeaderT struct {
    MagicValue [8]byte
    BodyLength [4]byte
    BodyVersion [1]byte
    ...
}
```

Comment: Even having a single non-public field in your structure will trigger this message.